# Processing queue members

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, queue, parallel-processing

I have a thread which fills a queue. And I have another thread which process this queue. My problem is first thread fills the queue very fast so the other thread couldn't process this queue that much faster and my program keeps overuse ram. What is the optimum solution for this problem?

Sorry I forgot to add something. I can't limit my queue or producer thread. My producer thread couldn't wait because it's capturing network packets and I shouldn't miss any packet. I have to process these packets fast than producer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that the order of processing of items in the queue is not important, you can run two (or more) threads processing the queue.

Unless there's some sort of contention between them, that should enable faster processing. This is known as a multi-consumer model.

Another possibility is to have your producer thread monitor the size of the queue and refuse to add entries until it drops below some threshold. Standard C# queues don't provide a way to stop expansion of the capacity (even using a 1.0 growth factor will not inhibit growth).

Comment: do you think using more than one queue is better? And should i use parallel library of .net 4.0?

Comment: No, I don't think multiple threads will be that much better. By concentrating them into one queue, you automatically load balance all the consumers (if, for example, some jobs take longer than others). That's not possible with multiple queues. I can't comment on NET4 or parallel library, I've never used or investigated it.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a maximum queue size (let's say 2000) which when hit causes the queue to only accept more items when it's down to a lower size (let's say 1000).

I'd recommend using an EventWaitHandle or a ManualResetEvent in order not to busy-wait. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are already doing so, use `BlockingCollection<T>` as your queue and pass some reasonable limit to the `boundedCapacity` parameter of constructor (which is then reflected in `BoundedCapacity` property) - your producer will block on `Add` if this would make the queue too large and resume after consumer has removed some element from the queue.

According to [MSDN documentation for `BlockingCollection<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137.aspx):

If a bounded capacity was specified when this instance of `BlockingCollection<T>` was initialized, a call to Add may block until space is available to store the provided item.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to new() X inter-thread comms instances at startup, put them on a queue and never create any more.  Thread A pops objects off this pool queue, fills them with data and queues them to thread B. Thread B gets the objects, processes them and then returns them to the pool queue.

This provides flow control - if thread A tries to post too fast, the pool will dry up and A will have to wait on the pool queue until B returns objects.  It has the potential to improve peformance since there are no mallocs and frees after the initial pool filling - the lock time on a queue push/pop will be less than that of a memory-manager call.  There is no need for complex bounded queues - any old producer-consumer queue class will do.  The pool can be used for inter-thread comms throughout a full app with many threads/threadPools, so flow-controlling them all.  Shutdown problems can be mitigated - if the pool queue is created by the main thread at startup before any forms etc and never freed, it is often possible to avoid explicit background thread shutdowns on app close - a pain that would be nice to just forget about.  Object leaks and/or double-releases are easily detected by monitoring the pool level, ('detected', not 'fixed':).

The inevitable downsides - all the inter -thread comms instance memory is permanently allocated even if the app is completely idle.  An object popped off the pool will be full of 'garbage' from the previous use of it.  If the 'slowest' thread gets an object before releasing one, it is possible for the app to deadlock with the pool empty and all objects queued to the slowest thread.  A very heavy burst of loading may cause the app to throttle itself 'early' when a simpler 'new/queue/dispose' mechanism would just allocate more instances and so clope better with the burst of work.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution would be that the producer thread check if the queue has reached a certain limit of pending items, if so then go to sleep before pushing more work.
Other solutions depend on what the actual problem you are trying to solve, is the processing more IO bound or CPU bound etc, that will even allow you to design the solution which doesn't even need a queue. For ex: The producer thread can generate, lets say 10 items, and call another consumer "method" which process them in parallel and so on.